# Onix files connected to Shopify or Wordpress [help]

Tags: database, wordpress, shopify, onix

What is the best system or method to bulk upload onix data into either a wordpress website or the shopify platform. I use the accumen book software to manage the onix files and I'm looking to feed information into the book selling page, and across the whole website.

I'm not looking to get too technical, as I can't implement this myself but am looking for answers in what I would like to direct a programmer/developer to do. I'm a designer by trade, and once the website is designed, I'm hoping to hire someone to handle the back-end and the integration of the database via onix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with a project that pulls ONIX files into WordPress. Try WP All Import plugin, it lets you define what field you want to pull from the ONIX file.
You will have to get the full/paid version of the plugin if you want to import into custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a setup where a Logstash instance slurps ONIX records from a CouchDB via the [couchdb_changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-couchdb_changes.html) input plugin, filters, modifies and enhances them and pushes them to Shopify via their API.

Logstash so far proves to be a very versatile tool for that, just have a look at their different kind of plugins: Input, [Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html) and Output. Sure, originally it's a tool to aggregate, process and forward logs, but it seems to have come a long way since that.

Logstash then just treats the records (and their updates) as an event stream, that you can operate on. I particularly like the ruby filter plugin that lets you execute custom Ruby code on the records/events.

The tricky part seems to ensure testability with having lots of custom code executed by Logstash. But I'm sure I'll figure something out.

Answer (score 1):

For super simple approach I'd recommend you do the following in Shopify

- Upload your ONIX feed to the files section of your website  https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/online-store/file-uploads
- Create a URL redirect in Shopify to that file location https://help.shopify.com/manual/migrating-to-shopify/url-redirect that is something like /onix.xml
- Tell your developer to access the url redirect (/onix.xml) you made periodically. If the data has changed use the products and variants API calls to make changes accordingly.
- When you update your ONIX information, upload the new file and pint the URL redirect there.